Choosing between a linear regulator and a zener diode
I am building an embedded circuit for a home project. I have a voltage source providing 5 V and a maximum current of 200 mA (or 500 mA peak), and I want to use it to connect my 3.3 V homemade device. I hesitate between two designs:

This seems to be the cleaner solution.

This is the cheaper, and it may be sufficient.
Which one do you recommend, and why?

If of any use: It is an ESP8266 that I'm connecting to a Roomba robot vacuum cleaner. There is a PTC resetable fuse that will reset if I exceed 200 mA. The maximum rated current for ESP8266 is 120mA, but it probably won't exceed 70 mA.

The zener schematic component values are completely wrong. Even if you used a short circuit as the output load, you will be able to get 0.33 milliamps through your load.

you don't want to leave that circuit connected to a roomba, less it will drain the battery. don't ask how i know, but i barely got it re-charged manually after just a day or two with an esp8266 attached.

Cyril, there's almost no good reason to avoid the AMS1117. It operates with the given overhead and provides many important features. A zener design could be modified (not the one you show, exactly) to use an NPN BJT and an added diode, with the zener. And it may satisfy -- maybe. But why? Other discrete techniques may even be "reasonable" over some temp range. But it is just more work without the advantages, unless you are making a lot of these and the difference between a handfull of 0.1 cent parts vs the AMS1117 matters. (I bought my lifetime supply of BJTs at 90 per penny. But thousands.)

@periblepsis There are a number of good reasons to avoid the AMS1117. The original LM1117, which the AMS1117 is a clone of, is perfectly usable, but the AMS1117 is generally much less reliable and more prone to oscillating in my experience. The TLV1117 and NCP1117/NCV1117 are also quite usable.

@Hearth I know nothing about the AMS1117. But it just stands as an icon for others in my comment, whose point mostly is about not doing this discrete unless large numbers are involved and the time spent is paid for.

Neither circuit, though the AMS1117 is at least salvageable. If you read the datasheet, you'll find this important note:

Stability
The circuit design used in the AMS1117 series requires the
use of an output capacitor as part of the device frequency
compensation. The addition of 22µF solid tantalum on the output will
ensure stability for all operating conditions. When the adjustment
terminal is bypassed with a capacitor to improve the ripple rejection,
the requirement for an output capacitor increases. The value of 22µF
tantalum covers all cases of bypassing the adjustment terminal.
Without bypassing the adjustment terminal smaller capacitors can be
used with equally good results. To further improve stability and
transient response of these devices larger values of output capacitor
can be used.

You need the output capacitor or the AMS1117 could oscillate and damage your load. The datasheet recommends a solid tantalum capacitor, and nothing else.
It may be possible to use a ceramic capacitor with a series resistor but evaluation of the actual capacitance of that ceramic part at 3.3V (it could be way, way, less than the nominal capacitance) would be required.
In many cases, it's also advisable to have an input capacitor, something like 10uF or more. It can be ceramic.


Which one do you recommend, and why?

The Zener circuit cannot be recommended because if you expect 120 mA to pass through a 10 kΩ resistor, the input voltage will need to be 1203.3 volts.
The preferred circuit would use a voltage regulator or, if you want you can lower the 10 kΩ resistor to a value that drops 1.7 volts across it when it conducts 120 mA (about 14 Ω), it should be OK but, not as good as a regulator in terms of output accuracy. The Zener diode will always be conducting 120 mA when the output load is disconnected, because the 14 Ω (the right value resistor) will always be conducting 120 mA.
Hence, one of the reasons we use a voltage regulator is that it won't consume 120 mA on light loads.

The second circuit will not work for the simple reason that a 10k resistor will need 1200 volts across it to pass 120mA. Zeners are useful for generating reference voltages or clamping inputs (non-exhaustive list), but for regulating a supply rail, you need a switching regulator or a linear regulator.

Does a 3.3 V zener even exist?

yes, 3.3 is in E12 so there should be several

While others have explained that you should use the regulator IC, and not a zener diode, I'll just throw in some extra details to help you understand why. The zener diode is used as a "shunt" regulator. In this design, there must always be 120mA flowing, but the diode will "shunt" any unused current through itself, so the load only gets what it needs. In fact, you should aim for slightly more than 120mA, say 130mA, to give the shunt some overhead to work with.
This means you have to choose a resistor low enough to pass 130mA when it has \$5V - 3.3V = 1.7V\$ across it, with or without the load present! By Ohm's law:
$$ R = \frac{1.7V}{130mA} = 13\Omega $$
To illustrate the idea of current shunting, and also why the zener diode really isn't that good at it, take a look at the circuit's behaviour without a load (left) and with one (right):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
On the left, with no load, all current flows through the zener diode. On the right though, when I add a resistive load to draw approximately 120mA, the 130mA total is split (see Kirchhoff's Current Law) between two paths; the zener diode and the load.
You can also see that when there's lots of current through the zener diode (left), it develops well over 3.3V. When that current is diverted away via the load, so that diode current falls to only 14mA, the diode develops significantly less than 3.3V. It's a terrible voltage regulator really. It certainly won't regulate as well as a proper active linear regulator, and it will waste significantly more power.
Higher voltage zener diodes perform better in this respect, so don't tar them all with the same brush. Low voltage zeners diodes are just really bad compared to their higher-voltage cousins, but they all have similar quirks, and none of them can compete with the precision or efficiency of an active regulator in this application.
